# Is "tartar" more common than "scale" in dentistry?

Tags: phrase-usage, american-english, british-english

According to my study, some British people say "**a buildup of scale on my teeth**" and both British and American people say "**a buildup of tartar on my teeth**".

The British also say "**to scale my teeth**".

I brought this question up because my sister's husband is Australian (but his father was British who moved to Australia 30 or 40 years ago) and he said "**...scale on my teeth**" and "**... got my teeth scaled**".

It seems googling "*scale of my teeth*" does not show as many hits as "*tartar of my teeth*".

Do American people say "*scale of my teeth*" and "*to scale my teeth*"?

Is "**tartar**" more common than "**scale**" in dentistry?

Comment: This seems to be a technical question and the technical forum is [medicalsciences.se]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is technical (subject: dentistry).

Comment: Also, calculus, i.e., little stones: https://www.goldenstatedentistry.com/blog/dental-tartar-calculus-causes-prevention-and-removal (One does not get calculus just from apples, though.)

Comment: There are multiple questions here. Which is more common in dentistry is a technical question. Whether non-medical-professional Americans say "scale" is on-topic; Google NGrams suggests that "scale from teeth" is almost unheard-of compared to "tartar from teeth". Although some Americans probably say it, if only because they were raised elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I’m an American, and I have never heard it called “scale” prior to seeing this question. All of my dentists have only used the term tartar.

Comment: From an Australian - all my dentists have used "tartar". I was aware of "scale" and would probably have interpreted it correctly without reading the question, but I hear it applied more to deposits in water heaters etc.

Comment: @Peter -  In Britain, it is very common to get a [scale and polish](https://www.corsodyl.co.uk/caring-for-your-gums/what-is-a-scale-and-polish/) when you visit a dentist, and I have seen the term used in other British English-speaking countries like Nigeria, Singapore, and New Zealand. The procedure can be done by a dentist or hygienist. The first ‘scrape’ stage removes the deposits of plaque and tartar. The next step is to 'polish' the teeth.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, yes "scale and polish" does ring a bell. Recently though I can only recall dentists using "tartar" as a name for the substance.